# How can i know touched which game object with Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, raycasting

I am using Unity3D, and i programming augmented reality. If i touch the screen and the touched position has one object, I will do something.
Actually I want "How can i know touched which game object ?

My code is here:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Atak : MonoBehaviour {
    private Animator anim;
    private GameObject kamera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        kamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Kamera");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        RaycastHit dokunma;
        if (Physics.Raycast(kamera.transform.position,Input.mousePosition,10)&&
            dokunma.collider.gameObject.tag=="Oyuncu" && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
        ){

            anim.SetBool ("Bekle", false);
            anim.SetBool ("Saldir", true);
        } else{
            anim.SetBool ("Bekle", true);
            anim.SetBool ("Saldir", false);
        }
    }
}
```

The editor gives me error:

> Use of unassigned local variable'dokunma'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not assign anything to the `dokunma`(RaycastHit) variable. Note that you have to pass in the `dokunma` variable to the `Physics.Raycast` function with the `out` keyword so that it will be initialized and result of the raycast will be stored in it.

```
void Update()
{
    Ray rayCast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit dokunma;
    if (Physics.Raycast(rayCast, out dokunma, 10) &&
        dokunma.collider.gameObject.tag == "Oyuncu" && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
    )
    {

        anim.SetBool("Bekle", false);
        anim.SetBool("Saldir", true);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetBool("Bekle", true);
        anim.SetBool("Saldir", false);
    }
}
```

It makes more sense to check for touch press first before performing the raycast. Always use the `CompareTag` function to compare tags. Something below should do it.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray rayCast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit dokunma;
        if (Physics.Raycast(rayCast, out dokunma, 10))
        {
            if (dokunma.collider.CompareTag("Oyuncu"))
            {

                anim.SetBool("Bekle", false);
                anim.SetBool("Saldir", true);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetBool("Bekle", true);
                anim.SetBool("Saldir", false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code I posted and I can't see your current code. Please copy the new `Update` function in my answer to your code and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you for answer but i don't use main camera. I use vuforia camera and i can not Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay. And please check my Start function i set name kamera.

Comment: If this is the case then replace `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)` with `kamera.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);`